# How to scrape data from website with "Load more" button with JS

Tags: javascript, web, dom, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the Google Scholar website with JS. The table is loaded with a "Load more" button at the bottom. For reference, see this page: https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=m8dFEawAAAAJ

Apparently I used btn.click() on the "Load more" button until the button was "Disabled" . Then, I **scraped** the data. Can somebody show me a better way to scrape the entire table data?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the `Show more` button, you can see that the next request is made with the following query string attached to the end of the url:

```
&cstart=20&pagesize=80
```

With `cstart` probably referencing something like count start, you could swap the parameter values to something like this, which should display the next 1000 items starting with the first:

```
https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=m8dFEawAAAAJ&cstart=1&pagesize=1000
```

Comment: @ADITYABISOI Correct.

Comment: This doesn't  work with pages such as this https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=3EYdp4oAAAAJ&hl=en